# Select ListView's row rather than the item

Tags: android, listview

I have created a listview using the default ArrayAdapter. However, to select an item from the list I have to tap the item and not just the row. How can I change it in order to just click the row the item is in rather than the item itself?

Here is the code for my listview:

```
    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, ans));
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int i,
                long l) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Selected option"+i);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    });
```

Here is the xml for the listview:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Here is the row.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
style="@style/list_answers"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your child views of the row to include `android:focusable="false"`. This will allow you to click the whole row. Right now, since each individual view thinks it can gain focus, they happen "on top" of the row.

P.S. What we really need is the XML for the ROW of the ListView. Not the ListView itself. :)

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: I added the row.xml Do you mean to add that in textview?

Comment: Yes sir. That is often the fix to that exact problem. I will often add `android:clickable="false"` for good measure, but in most circumstances that is not necessary.

Comment: If your row contained multiple views, you would include that in each of the views. :)

Comment: i tired it but nothing changed...:(

Comment: This is probably because your row is just a TextView, so there is no "parent" for it to move the click to. If you were to nest the TextView inside a RelativeLayout, (and even have another sibling) you would see the difference right away. The issue here is that, if there is no "parent", fill_parent only fills the parent if the content is "big" enough. If there is a parent, fill_parent does exactly what you tell it to. One has to remember that each View is normally a composite View itself, so the rules don't necessarily cascade down, unless given the opportunity.

Comment: The thing is by using "parent", either relativelayout or linearlayout, my listview doesnt work at all beacuse  ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: I googled that issued and it seems to be solved. So know it seems to work as intented:) Thanks